# Manually creating an UploadedFile

Tags: php, yii2

I have this code:

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
```

And I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to generate this `UploadedFile` manually (I need some hidden file uploads). Since `UploadedFile` seems to be more than just the content and file_put_content/fopen don't seem to work in the directory I'm in (I guess restricted access), I have no idea how to do this.

It seems I have to generate either a `UploadedFile` type or some other structure that contains a file with all info, not just the content.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Didi you checked that [getInstance()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile#getInstances()-detail) returns file details and not just name?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If the file is sent properly in post data, then you should be able to use `UploadedFile::getInstance()` it shouldn't matter whether the input was visible or hidden. If you are not sending file in post data then you shouldn't need to use `UploadedFile`.